# Function to export multiple yfinance stocks to csv

Tags: python, function, yahoo-finance, yfinance, stockquotes

I'm trying to define a function to allow me to extract information on stocks over the past 12 months and export it to a CSV file. I'm not sure where it's going wrong as it prints 'bad'. Any thoughts?
Thanks.

```
import pandas as py
import numpy as np
import yfinance as yf
import datetime as dt
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials

yf.pdr_override()


now_time=dt.datetime.now()
start_time = dt.datetime(now_time.year - 1, now_time.month , now_time.day)

bad_names=[]

def download_stock(stock):
    try:
        print(stock)
        stock_df = pdr.get_yahoo_data(stock, start_time, now_time)
        stock_df['Name'] = stock
        output_name = stock + '_data.csv'
        stock_df.to_csv("./stocks/"+output_name)
    except:
        bad_names.append(stock)
        print('bad: %s' % (stock))

download_stock('AAPL')
```

Comment: [`pdr.get_data_yahoo`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/blob/main/pandas_datareader/data.py#L79) not `pdr.get_yahoo_data`. I'm voting to close the question as caused by a typo.

Answer (score 0):

A `try - except` block will handle any exception and simply execute what follows after except.

You could try running the code without the `try-except` block and see what the error is.

Alternatively, you could use

```
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

So you can know what is going wrong exactly. Looking at it now, I would guess that you are missing one dot in the filepath `"../stocks/"+output_name`